# Failure to process openvino dnn recognizer on NCS2 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, face-recognition, openvino

I am trying to run a face detector/face recognizer python script on my Raspberry Pi 4 with the Intel NCS2 device.
I am running on the Pi 4 with OpenCV and Openvino installed per the excellent blogs at pyimagesearch.com.

Face detection runs with this code, set up to target the NCS2 (myriad) device:

```
detector = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe("face_detection_model/deploy.prototxt",              
                "face_detection_model/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel")
detector.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_MYRIAD)
```

The detector runs with

```
     imageBlob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(
        cv2.resize(image, (300, 300)), 1.0, (300, 300),
        (104.0, 177.0, 123.0), swapRB=False, crop=False)
     detector.setInput(imageBlob)
     detections = detector.forward()
```

The face detector works great and runs smoothly.

But, then, I set up an image recognizer on the face that the detector finds.

```
embedder = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTorch("face_embedding_model/openface.nn4.small2.v1.t7"])
embedder.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_MYRIAD)
```

And then I invoke it with the image of the face, based on detection box

```
        face = image[startY:endY, startX:endX]
        (fH, fW) = face.shape[:2]
        faceBlob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(face, 1.0 / 255, (96, 96),
            (0, 0, 0), swapRB=True, crop=False)
        embedder.setInput(faceBlob)
        vec = embedder.forward()
```

But, when it gets to vec=embedder.forward(), the following error gets thrown

```
Failed to Initialize Inference Engine backend : Device with “CPU” name is not registered in the InferenceEngine in function ‘initPlugin’
```

I have no idea why the function is correctly targeted to the NCS2 for the detection, but fails to run for the recognizer.

From what I can tell, it is trying to run the recognizer code on the CPU, not the NCS2.  The Intel openvino libraries supposedly don't support the Raspberry Pi Arm processor, so it throws the error.

I have tried using various other setPreferableTarget and SetPreferrableBackend settings from the OpenCV documentation.  According to the documentation, the only allowable combo with the myriad is is a target of DNN_TARGET_MYRIAD and a backend of DNN_BACKEND_INFERENCE_ENGINE.  But no combination works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you first initialize the recognizer model, do you get the error on the detector then? Can you try assigning multiple detectors to the myriad?

Comment: Interesting suggestion. 
Changing the code to initialize the recognizer first does not fix it.  I still get the same error message.
I can assign a second detector and it seems to run on the myriad.  Interestingly enough, the detector parameters are different for the same image.  I'm not sure what is going on here.

Comment: Which OpenCV and OpenVINO version are you using? I have a guess that the network `face_embedding_model/openface.nn4.small2.v1.t7` cannot be executed on NCS2 and trying to fallback to CPU in that case. To confirm that I can suggest trying to run the network using standard application of OpenVINO. Please refer to https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_inference_engine_samples_benchmark_app_README.html for more information.

Comment: From the version.txt, I have OpenVINO vesrsion releases_2019_R3_InferenceEngine_30677, Sept 16, 2019

Comment: And OpenCV version 4.1.2-openvino.
I'm not quite clear as to what you mean by using "standard application of OpenVINO"  As far as I know, I don't think I can run any OpenVINO on the Raspberry Pi without the NCS2 device.

Comment: Update:  I created a test program that removes the detector, and has the recognizer run on an image cropped to a single face.  And it fails again.

So, at least I know it is not caused by trying to execute two different functions on the NCS2.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. By standard application I meant application based on OpenVINO Inference Engine API. OpenCV is a fronted for Inference Engine and it may hide some things from it's user.

Answer (score 1):

Artemy's comment got me thinking about versions, so I looked into a version warning that I thought was unrelated.  It turns out that it was a version conflict in sklearn that was somehow blocking the running of the recognizer on the NCS2. Installing the old 0.20.2 version of scikit-learn fixed it.

This really confuses me, since I wasn't expecting the MYRIAD calls to be dependent on a python library.  Maybe I accidentally changed another setting somewhere.

Interestingly enough, for my video application, the first pass of the recognizer takes ~30 seconds, but after that it takes only ~50 ms per face.

Comment: Nice to know that you managed to resolve the issue! And yep, agree, the root cause of such behavior is unclear.

Comment: Regarding the long first iteration. OpenCV Inference Engine backend implemented in this way: on the first iteration it calls LoadNetwork method. For NCS2 device it means to do transformation of a network to format which can be executed by device and then load that transformed network to the device. This is a pretty heavy operations. Then it just is processing images which does not take much time. If time of first iteration is critical to you, there is a way to avoid it. But you have to use Inference Engine API instead. Let me know if you are interested in details.

Comment: Thank you for that info about LoadNetwork was very helpful.  I can live with a long startup, as long as I know that it is normal.  Your questions did inspire me to look at versions, so you were a help.